# ROC Convex Hull for Model Selection

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc, convex

The area under the **convex hull** of a *roc* curve is by construction always "better" than its area under curve. Some curves might see more of an increase in reported *auc* than others. Is it a viable approach to prefer classifiers that "benefit more" from this approach in model selection?

A classifier that performs decent over the entire range of fpr-tpr thresholds could be discarded in favor of a classifier that excels in a specific region in the roc space and underperforms in others. The second classifier might be preferable regarding properties of its convex hull.

I am not sure whether to include this in a cross-validation process.

Comment: I think you touch upon something very important: The fact that AUC is *not* an all-encompassing truth but rather a single number. As you correctly say, if we know that a particular range of TPR or FPR is more relevant for an application then we should focus there. Similarly though we should recognise that if our ideal performance is unattainable (e.g. a classifier with 90%+ precision where we would have nonsensically low recall for a particular application), using AUC gives us a good indication what would be a generally useful classifier instead of one based on an arbitrary threshold.

Comment: I think that this answer can give you a better insight to your question.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/132856

I feel that you want to know how to create the best classifier using a convex hull of roc curves between different models (?)

Comment: I know how to combine them - but due to properties of them convex hull, shouldn't the model selection change, since two "better classifiers" do not necessarily result in a better convex hull.